# Accessing django session data

Tags: django

While reading the docs I understood that django session is accessed using the request object. What happens when there are multiple views? Should I use the same 'request' object in all views to access the session data? (I'm new to django :) )

Comment: Every request is handled by a single view which gets a request object passed. So basicly it is never "the same object". Even not between to requests handled by the same view. The session will be automatically attached to the request object for every request by the `SessionMiddleware` which fetches the session data from the database. So yes, every view can access the session data.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't really make sense.

`request` is the first parameter to every view. You access the session via that object that is passed to your view.

Comment: I understood that part. What I'm trying to ask is can another view access this session data (read /write)

Comment: I still don't understand. All views are passed the request object. If it's the same user, then of course the view will have access to the same session data; that's the *entire purpose* of sessions.

Answer (score 0):

you have spesial table in your DB with name django_sessions
it has `session_key` which is same as value in cookies, you can view in brouser

So in `view` you just deal with value from cookies, so it is same for one user in one browser and different for diffirent users, no matter of `view`